# Gmail id verfication using Oauth 2.0 to authenticate android app

Tags: android

I am creating one android app, in which I want user to login with it's Gmail id and password.
And it should be authenticated from the google server.
I am using the OAuth 2.0. I have done following steps as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp

1. Register my app on console
2. Generate Clint id, client secrete and API key.
3. I have created request url as :

> String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(client_id, redirect_url, scope).build();
>   
>   redirect_url : "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", 
>   scope : "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/siteverification"

1. Post this url for response.

In response, it opens up a dialogue box to enter user name again. I want to generate token in background. I don't want to show dialog box for authenticating user on requested url.

Please suggest me what should do here.

Thanks

Comment: bad idea ... it is not how oauth works ... you have to redirect user to browser they trust, not ask user for username and password ...

Comment: @Selvin, thanks for the response, I have a web application which requires gmail credentials to login. I am creating android app for the same. In my app I want to implement login page which will ask for credentials and if these are valid user will be redirected to second page of app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966965/best-way-to-use-google-apis-using-oauth-2-0-on-android